# EditText fromHtml can not convert &amp; to &

Tags: android, webview

I have a editText which is showing Html contents but when I try to show &amp as & it does not work. It's still showing &amp.

How I am doing it -

```
description.setText(Html.fromHtml("Locator &amp;amp; Navigator ( Location )"));
```

Comment: **&amp;amp;** are sure you aren't missing anything

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String value = "some value &amp;amp; some other value";
description.setText(Html.fromHtml(value.replaceAll("&amp;amp;","amp;")));
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I am sorry it is like this actually - Locator &amp;amp; Navigator ( Location ) It's coming from server actually

Comment: The server returns `amp;` two times? then I think the server's response is incorrect.

Comment: @HongDuan agree with u

Comment: @Anirban You can always replace `&amp;amp;` with `&amp;`